# Tensorflow regression model giving same prediction every time

Tags: python, regression

> > > ```
> > > import tensorflow as tf
> > >
> > > x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,4])    # input vector    
> > >
> > > w1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([4,2]))   # weights between first and second layers
> > >
> > > b1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([2]))             # biases added to hidden layer
> > >
> > > w2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([2,1]))   # weights between second and third layer
> > >
> > > b2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]))             # biases added to third (output) layer
> > >
> > > def feedForward(x,w,b):                     # function for forward propagation
> > > ```

```
          Input = tf.add(tf.matmul(x,w), b)

          Output = tf.sigmoid(Input)

          return Output


>>> Out1 = feedForward(x,w1,b1)                # output of first layer

>>> Out2 = feedForward(Out1,w2,b2)             # output of second layer

>>> MHat = 50*Out2                             # final prediction is in the range (0,50)



>>> M = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,1])   # placeholder for actual (target value of marks)

>>> J = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(MHat - M))    # cost function -- mean square errors                          

>>> train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.05).minimize(J)     # minimize J using Gradient Descent

>>> sess = tf.InteractiveSession()             # create interactive session 

>>> tf.global_variables_initializer().run()    # initialize all weight and bias variables with specified values

>>> xs = [[1,3,9,7],    
          [7,9,8,2],                           # x training data
          [2,4,6,5]]

>>> Ms = [[47],
          [43],                                # M training data
          [39]]

>>> for _ in range(1000):                      # performing learning process on training data 1000 times

       sess.run(train_step, feed_dict = {x:xs, M:Ms})


>>> print(sess.run(MHat, feed_dict = {x:[[1,3,9,7]]}))
```

[[ 50.]]

```
>>> print(sess.run(MHat, feed_dict = {x:[[1,15,9,7]]}))
```

[[ 50.]]

```
>>> print(sess.run(tf.transpose(MHat), feed_dict = {x:[[1,15,9,7]]}))
```

[[ 50.]]

In this code, I am trying to predict the marks M of a student out of 50 given how many hours he/she slept, studied, used electronics and played. These 4 features come under the input feature vector x.

To solve this regression problem, I am using a deep neural network with
an input layer with 4 perceptrons (the input features) , a hidden layer with two perceptrons and an output layer with one perceptron. I have used sigmoid as activation function. But, I am getting the exact same prediction([[50.0]]) for M for all possible input vectors I feed in. Can someone please tell me
what is wrong with the code below. I HIGHLY APPRECIATE THE HELP! (IN ADVANCE)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to modify your `feedforward()` function. Here you don't need to apply `sigmoid()` at last layer (simply return the activation function!) and also no need to multiply output of this function by 50.

```
def feedForward(X,W1,b1,W2,b2):
    Z=tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(X,W1)+b1)
    return tf.matmul(Z,W2)+b2
MHat = feedForward(x,w1,b1,w2,b2)
```

Hope this helps!

*Don't forget to let us know if it solved your problem :)*

Comment: @Tarun if it solved your problem then you should mark it as correct answer. It'll certainly help others in case they face similar issue in future. Thanks!